# Bringing a Border into View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have this `TabItem`:

```
<TabItem x:Name="tabTFGWReadingMainHall" Header="Main Hall" DataContext="{Binding Meeting}">
    <TabItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberClasses, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingMain}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabItem.Style>
    <Border  x:Name="borderBibleReadingMain" BorderThickness="5">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingMain}">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberClasses, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>
            <Label Content="Student:"/>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBibleReadingMain" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" IsEnabled="False"
                        DataContext="{Binding TFGW.BibleReadingItem.Main}"
                        Text="{Binding DataContext.BibleReadingMain, ElementName=oclmEditor, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Button x:Name="buttonBibleReadingMain" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent"
                        DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
                            Command="{Binding ApplicationCommand}" CommandParameter="BibleReadingMain">
                    <Image Source="Images/AssignmentTypeBibleReading16.png" Margin="2"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Label Content="Study:"/>
            <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</TabItem>
```

As you can see, it has some `DataTriggers` implemented. Thus, when you change the **comboActiveStudentAssignmentType** (over on the right edge of the editor):

[image: Select Bible Reading Main from combo]

This is how the controls on the left change:

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

The DataTriggers are working right. The `Border` is set correctly and the `TabItem` gets selected. But, if possible, I would like to end up with this:

[image: Scroll to view]

I have done some research on this and it appears that I need to use [BringIntoView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bringintoview(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the desired results. But that needs to be called from the code behind. I added a SelectionChanged handler and did this:

```
private void comboActiveStudentAssignmentType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OCLMEditorViewModel vm = this.DataContext as OCLMEditorViewModel;
    if(borderBibleReadingMain != null && 
       vm.ActiveStudentAssignmentType == Data.StudentInfo.Enums.StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingMain)
        borderBibleReadingMain.BringIntoView();
    // TODO: Add others here
}
```

Whilst it did get fired, it did not seem to make any difference. I still had to scroll the reactangle to bring it into view.

How should I be doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want a red border around `TabItem`?

Comment: @StepUp No. The border I have is fine. I just wanted the whole border object to scroll into view, rather than stay cropped. Or rather, to *ensure* it is visible if possible (since user may have resized the panel).

Comment: The last time I did this I had zero time and cheated by just putting a named 1x1 transparent rect under the Border and put BringIntoView() against it instead to accomplish the same goal but without haveing to go measuring ActualHeight's and VerticalOffset's etc. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @ChrisW.Thanks. I will try it.